# Separating a string into groups

Tags: java, exception, methods

I need to write a method `groupify` which takes 2 parameters:

1. the string that I want to break into groups.
2. the  number of  letters per group.

So, the code may print a string which consists of the input string broken into groups with the number of letters specified on  the second parameters, if there aren't enough letters in the input string to fill out all the groups, it should fill the final group with `"x"`, so if I `groupify("HELLODANY",2)`, it must return `"HE LL OD AN YX"`

My code is the following:

```
package com.company;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    public static String gropify(String message,int number) {
        String result="";
        int len =message.length();
        int s=0;
        int n=3;
        for(int x=0;x<len;++n) {
            s = s + number;
            result = result + message.substring(x,s);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String message= "HELLODANY";
        System.out.println(gropify(message, 3));
    }
}
```

But I'm getting the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 12

What should I change?

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer a `StringBuilder` over many `String` concatenations (those create temporary immutable `String` instances). Next, you can test if the current index is evenly divisible by `number`, if it is then you add a space; then append the actual character to the `StringBuilder`. Finally, add padding by calculating the remainder of the message length divided by number - append that many `X`(s). Like,

```
public static String gropify(String message, int number) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
        if (i != 0 && i % number == 0) {
            sb.append(' ');
        }
        sb.append(message.charAt(i));
    }
    int pad = message.length() % number;
    for (int i = 0; i < pad; i++) {
        sb.append('X');
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Note that your current approach is flawed, you are adding to `s` in the loop body, when you hit `12` you exceed the length of your `message`.

Comment: @Charlesspi try to accept someone's answer if it saves your time.

Answer (score 1):

Method substring() is used for getting a substring of a particular String.

There are two variants of this method, please read carefully to understand the wrong use of substring method in your program and that is why you are getting the error.

`String substring(int beginIndex)`: Returns the substring starting from the specified index(beginIndex) till the end of the string. For e.g. `"Chaitanya".substring(2)` would return `"aitanya"`.

This method throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException` If the `beginIndex` is less than zero or greater than the length of String `(beginIndex<0||> length of String)`.

`String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)`: Returns the substring starting from the given index(`beginIndex`) till the specified index(`endIndex`).

For example, "`Chaitanya".substring(2,5)` would return `"ait"`.

It throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException` If `beginIndex` is less than zero OR `beginIndex > endIndex` OR `endIndex` is greater than the length of string.

Answer (score 1):

THE following code gives the correct result:

public static String groupify(String message, int size){

```
    if (size == 0) return message;

    String result = "";

    int iteration = message.length()/size;
    int count = 0;

    for (int i =0; i< iteration; i++){
        count = count + size;
        result = result + message.substring(i*size,count) + " ";
    }
    int iteration2 = message.length() % size;
    int padreq = size - iteration2;
    int lastalpha = message.length() - iteration2;

    if (iteration2 != 0) {
        result = result + message.substring(lastalpha);

        for (int j = 0; j < padreq; j++) {
            result = result + "x";
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```